# Compare two dates, not allowed to overlap the first agenda event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a calendar, and you can put some appointments on the agenda, but it is not allowed to have a second appointment on th first appointment. So it is not allowed that they intersect witch each other. I try it like this:

```
public bool IsOverlapping(AgendaEventViewModel viewModel, AgendaEventViewModel newItem)
        {
            bool isOverlapping = false;
            DateTime? begin = DateTime.Parse(viewModel.start);
            DateTime? end = DateTime.Parse(viewModel.end);

            newItem = new AgendaEventViewModel();
            DateTime begin2 = DateTime.Parse(newItem.start);
            DateTime end2 = DateTime.Parse(newItem.end);

           // TODO: Check if Event is Overlapping with other events :) Dynamic RoomRules Check should implemented here
            if (begin > end || begin2 > end2)
                isOverlapping = false;

            if (begin == end || begin2 == end2)
                isOverlapping = false; // No actual date range

            if (begin > end || begin2 > end2)
            {
                isOverlapping = false;
            }

            if (begin == begin2 && end == end2 )
            {
                isOverlapping = true;
                this.ShowMessage(Message.Type.Info, Resources.AgendaEvent.IsOverlapping);
            }

            if (begin < begin2)
            {
                if (end > begin2 && end < end2)
                    isOverlapping = true; // possible1

                if (end > end2)
                    isOverlapping = true; // possible 3
            }
            else
            {
                if (end2 > begin && end2 < end)
                    isOverlapping = true; // possible 2

                if (end2 > end)
                    isOverlapping = true; // possible 4
            }        
            return isOverlapping;
}
```

and this is the AgendaEventViewModel:

```
public class AgendaEventViewModel
    {
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public string id { get; set; }
        public int? funeralId { get; set; }
        public int? reservationId { get; set; }

        public int? roomId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Title", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.AgendaEvent))]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.AgendaEvent))]
        public string start { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.AgendaEvent))]
        public string end { get; set; }

        public string top { get; set; }
        public string left { get; set; }

        public List<RoomItemModel> RoomItems { get; set; }
        public List<CateringItemModel> CateringItems { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "SeatingCapacity", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.AgendaEvent))]
        public int? SeatingCapacity { get; set; } //Max Room SeatingCapacity

        [Display(Name = "ExpectedSeatingCapacity", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.AgendaEvent))]
        public int? ExpectedSeatingCapacity { get; set; } // User Chosen
    }
```

but I get this error on this line:

DateTime begin2 = DateTime.Parse(newItem.start); with this error:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String reference not set to an instance of a String.

Thank you

ok, I have it now, like this:

```
public bool IsOverlapping(AgendaEventViewModel viewModel, AgendaEventViewModel newItem)
        {
            bool isOverlapping = false;
           // ReservationModel r = new ReservationModel(int.Parse(viewModel.id));
            DateTime? begin = DateTime.Parse(viewModel.start);
            DateTime? end = DateTime.Parse(viewModel.end);


            newItem = new AgendaEventViewModel();
            newItem.start = "2014-08-11 10:00:00.000";
            newItem.end = "2014-08-11 11:00:00.000";
            DateTime? begin2 = DateTime.Parse(newItem.start);
            DateTime? end2 = DateTime.Parse(newItem.end);

           // TODO: Check if Event is Overlapping with other events :) Dynamic RoomRules Check should implemented here
            if (begin > end || begin2 > end2)
                isOverlapping = false;

            if (begin == end || begin2 == end2)
                isOverlapping = false; // No actual date range



            if (begin > end || begin2 > end2)
            {
                isOverlapping = false;
            }


            //if ((begin  <= end2)  && (begin2  <= end))
            //{
            //    this.ShowMessage(Message.Type.Info, Resources.AgendaEvent.IsOverlapping);
            //    isOverlapping = true;
            //}

            if (begin == begin2 && end == end2)
            {
                this.ShowMessage(Message.Type.Info, Resources.AgendaEvent.IsOverlapping);
                isOverlapping = true;
            }

            if (begin < begin2)
            {
                if (end > begin2 && end < end2)
                    isOverlapping = true; // possible1

                if (end > end2)
                    isOverlapping = true; // possible 3
            }
            else
            {
                if (end2 > begin && end2 < end)
                    isOverlapping = true; // possible 2

                if (end2 > end)
                    isOverlapping = true; // possible 4
            }




            return isOverlapping;
        }
```

But If I put a second agenda item on the calendar, then begin en end will be override through end2 and begin2.

Comment: You're getting an ArgumentNullException on a function that only takes one argument.  I think that's a pretty good indication that newItem.start is null.  Look at your code -- you're wiping out the passed in newItem with newItem = new AgendaEventViewModel();.

Answer (score 0):

Your `newItem.start` is `null`, so when you try to parse it, it throws a `System.ArgumentNullException`. Make sure you set the date of you new item before you try to parse it.

Comment: Thank you, but how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to use the TryParse method.  Thet will tell you if it cannot parse the string into a DateTime.

```
        DateTime begin2;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(newItem.start, out begin2))
        {
            // handle error.
        }
```

But you have other issues that need to be addressed.

You are setting the isOverlapping and then you continue to do testing so it gets reset by later logic.  The actual return value will be the value of the last test.

Why are **begin** and **end** nullable DateTimes but **begin2** and **end2** regular DateTimes?

Some of this logic is testing for the overlap but other logic is validating that the begin and end values are legitimate values.  Maybe the validation logic should be split out into a separate process so you know that there were errors.  You are doing validation but reporting it as a non-overlap result.